Using a remote cli python project remotely
I have a cli python project that I want to run remotely on a free python host. My aim is to allow people to use the python project without giving them the source code. I want them to be able to run it without me having to rewrite the project. I know I can rewrite the project turning it into web service using flask module. Though, that requires rewriting. I have researched this topic and came to the conclusion that I am able to do that using ssh and docker. Though, all python free hosts, I came across, either do not provide access to them or restrict outgoing internet connection.
Here is my question. Is there any different way of accomplishing what I want other than using ssh and docker? Note that the project requires continuous user input and it uses the internet.
Thank you.

You compile your python cli into an exectuable. Look into pyinstaller https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/.

Thank you for the reply. Though, pyinstaller .exe can be easily decompiled to acquire the source code.
